# Consensus on Uri.parse("content://sms");

Tags: android, parsing, sms, uri

What is the consensus on parsing the Uri of sms messages for use with a cursor. There has to be a cross phone compatible way of getting access to sms messages.

There's nothing in the sdk for something like this?

What about this as a Uri string: ("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the source for [SMSPopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/)

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"),
               projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: But this apparently is not part of the SDK and does not respond consistently on all phones. It works fine on the Droid Incredible, but I am having trouble with it on the Moto Droid.

Comment: I have a Droid and SMSPopup definitely works so post the non-working code.

Comment: I'm using the Uri to delete a text message at a particular thread location (Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations" + threadId), which doesn't work on the Droid, but works on the Incredible just fine. When I code tonight I will change it to sms-mms to see if it works. I've heard sms-mms is more cross phone compatible.

Comment: failed for me when i substituted sms-mms for sms:


06-22 14:44:00.582 E/ActivityThread( 1748): Failed to find provider info for sms-mms